# Next.js rewrites - access original request parameters

Tags: url-rewriting, next.js

I am building a navigation system for a Next.js app that would have routes like

- http://localhost:3000/docs/section1/pageName
- http://localhost:3000/docs/section2/pageName
- etc

Under the hood these routes will point to a page `/docs/:slug` which is achievable with rewrites:

```
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/docs/section1/:slug',
        destination: '/docs/:slug'
      },
      {
        source: '/docs/section2/:slug',
        destination: '/docs/:slug'
      }
    ];
  }
```

But I'd like to pass the `sectionN` as a context variable to the destination path. So that the `slug` page could know which section was referred to originally. The purpose is to minimize the amount of underlying pages but to keep the pages navigation meaningful to user or search bot.

I understand that rewrites support/api can be limited. Checking the `context` in `getInitialProps` - original artificats are not available.  Is there a way maybe to approach this differently in Next.js?

Comment: Why not define the page as /docs/:section/:slug

Comment: Thanks @felixmosh That sounds like a totally working solution. I keep learning the next.js and its dynamic routing.

Answer (score 0):

@felixmosh suggested in a comment to simply go with next.js dynamic routing that allows to use multiple slugs in the paths, no need to use rewrites.
That works!

Here goes the link to the official manual - https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes.

Answer (score 0):

Found solition:

```
async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/work/:slug/:path*',
        destination: '/work/:slug',
      },
    ]
  },
```